# Try/Catch in Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, try-catch

```
public class MyClass{

    private String url;
    private static InputSource is;

    public MyClass(String link){
        this.url=link;
        try {
            is = new InputSource();
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            is.setByteStream(new URL(url).openStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debug(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have three methods and I'am using `InputSource` in all methods. So I want to create one `InputSource` with constructor and use it in all methods. How can I do it? Does anyone have any idea? Should I use try-cath block in constructor?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: This looks a bit confusing. what do you think will happen if you create two instances of `MyClass`, while trying to read/write to the InputSource of two different URL connections?

Comment: Are you sure you want to make `InputSource is` a static variable? Don't unless you are confident and know what `static` means.

Answer (score 8):

Using `try`/`catch` in the constructor is fine, but I wouldn't swallow the exception like that.

You will potentially end up with a partially-initialized instance that will fail later when you try to use it.

E.g. in this case, you might end up with `is` being `null`. This might be fine for some operations on that class, but it might be dereferenced in some obscure code path, leading to a very hard-to-debug issue, since the exception in the constructor happened much earlier.

A more subtle (read: far worse) bug would be if setting the encoding failed, leaving your input source not configured to read UTF-8 text correctly. This would then give you back garbage, potentially, but you wouldn't know as it would be "valid" garbage. (Actually, this is unlikely to happen, as UTF-8 encoding has to be supported by specification. However, as a general strategy, silent failures should be avoided).

I would propagate the exception somehow, either by simply declaring `throws` on the constructor, or rethrow the exception as an unchecked exception (if appropriate).

Additionally, I would not `catch`/declare `throws` `Exception`: this masks the fact that specific exception types can be thrown, when those exceptions would need to be handled in a specific way (e.g. `InterruptedException`).

Answer (score 1):

If the InputSource constructor can throw an exception, I don't see why your constructor can't. You have two options, doing what you are doing, but avoiding using a [pokemon exception handler](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html), and handling it properly; or, for better error handling, you should make your constructor throw a custom exception.

**EDIT** In case the link breaks, a pokemon exception handler is the one you use when you just Gotta Catch 'Em All.

```
try {
  // do something
} catch {
  // catch em all
}
```

Comment: I liked the linked page :) but I think it might be more helpful to explain what you mean by "pokemon exception hendler" in your answer, in case that link dies.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use try-catch as you can use it in regular methods.

Comment: Formally can, but sometimes this can be anti-pattern like write Andy

Comment: He's already using it, so that wasn't really the question, was it?

Comment: His question:  "Should I use try-cath block in constructor?" Nothing stops him from using it. If he ignores exception in catch block it's a problem (excepts if he wants that, depending on the situation). Maybe he will need to throw only a type of exception and his code throws another type, than he will be forced to use try-catch and wrap the exception in his allowed one.

Comment: Consider this: OP has an application that uses a library. He does not have access to the application, he has access to the library. In the application a constructor from the library is called that throws a custom NoDataException because the library read data from somewhere(lets say a file). But if OP now reads the data from a database he cannot throw SQLException but it will be forced to use try-catch to catch the SQLExcpetion and wrap it to NoDataException. So do not hurry with the minuses because questions cannot all be interview questions.